# iOS Two Cells in one Row With Data

Tags: ios, uitableview

This has been driving me absolutely insane ever since I started this app.  Basically I have a UITableViewCell with an image and a label and I want to have another UITableViewCell with image and label of the next result right next to it in the same row.

Something like what PrettyKit does but without using that framework:

[image: Pretty Kit Example]

So... Let's say my database returned four results and the columns are id, text, and image. Those results would be id1, text1, image1, id2,text2, image2, id3, text3, image3, id4, text4, image4:

```
Image1 | Image2
Text1  | Text2

Image3 | Image4
Text3  | Text4
```

and so on.

I already have a xib with exactly that layout... and I know I can put two buttons side by side in one row... but I have no idea how to populate my image views and text views so that the data could be side by side in one row.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Decided to give UICollectionView a shot as it seems to be the best solution for what I want to do. But ran into a bit of trouble converting my TableView to a CollectionView. [xcode Converting UITableView to UICollectionView (no valid cell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696626/xcode-converting-uitableview-to-uicollectionview-no-valid-cell)

Comment: "and I want to have another UITableViewCell with image and label of the next result right next to it in the same row" No. It may look like two boxes, with two pairs of text, but it is still one UITableViewCell. Trust me on this one. :)

Comment: Oh I know it's just one cell. I just wanted to  figure out how to populate it with data from two different rows. :)

Comment: Then you are thinking about it wrong. Your data needs to be structured so that this is _one_ "row". One row with more data than the other rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this You can use `UICollection view controller`.

Or If you want to use the `Table view` then create the `custom cell` as per your requirement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696626/xcode-converting-uitableview-to-uicollectionview-no-valid-cell

Answer (score 1):

Your data source should be an array of custom objects (that have properties for left text, right text, left image, right image) or an array of dictionaries. something like this,

```
@[@{@"text1":@"whatever", "text2":@"something else", @"image1:@"someImageName.jpg", @"image2": @"someOtherImageNamejpg"}, @{@"text1":@"another string", "text2":@"yet another string", @"image1:@"differentImageName.jpg", @"image2": @"otherDifferentImageNamejpg"}]
```

In your table view controller, you populate the cells from this array,

```
    - (TableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.leftLabel.text = self.theData[indexPath.row][@"text1"];
        cell.rightLabel.text = self.theData[indexPath.row][@"text2"];
        cell.leftImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.theData[indexPath.row][@"image1"]];
        // etc.
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: So... if I'm reading you right... I would have to assign a "left/right" or "text1/text2" property to every object in my table?

Comment: @mysticcola If you need to populate two labels and two image views, then yes, every object needs to have those 4 pieces of data. There are other possible arrangements of the data, but this is one way to do it. How is your data structured now?

Comment: Well right now there's just the name, image, and description. And another column for category.  It seems like a collection view is really the way to go. I'm an old school dev... so I didn't even notice that collectionview was introduced in IOS 6.1 :)

Comment: @mysticcola Collection view would be the way to go if you consider text 1/image1 to belong to one object and text2/image2 to another.  On the other hand, if both texts and both images belong to the same object, then I would use a table view like I showed. Your question doesn't specify which is your situation.

Comment: Really? I thought that was pretty clear... Let's say my database returned four results and the columns are id, text, and image. Those results would be id1, text1, image1, id2,text2, image2, id3, text3, image3, id4, text4, image4. I'll copy that into the question.

Comment: @mysticcola ok, in that case I would use a collection view.

Comment: Ran into a bit of trouble with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696626/xcode-converting-uitableview-to-uicollectionview-no-valid-cell

Answer (score 0):

By design, table views only support one cell per row. You *could* still do this with a table view by having a custom cell which includes your content twice (left/right), but this has some massive drawbacks. You have to do index path calculations for everything you do. And what if you want to delete one element from the list? In that case you'd need to reload all rows below the affected row, because what was on the left is now on the right of the cell above. So, basically you loose most of the functionality that a table view provides you and just bend it heavily to do something that it's not designed for.

So, what's the solution? It's actually quite simple (assuming you are targeting iOS6+): Use a [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) with a [`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html).