# xcode Converting UITableView to UICollectionView (no valid cell)

Tags: xcode, layout, uicollectionview

EDIT: I should specify that this only happens when I attempt to use the UICollectionViewFlowLayout, not when I try to use a custom view. But either way nothing ever shows up on the CollectionView though it was working just fine before I converted from a TableView.)

So I've been trying to convert a UITableView that I had into a UICollectionView. So far so good. But when I try to run the app it gives me the error:

> 'the collection view's data source did not return a valid cell from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: for index path  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'

I checked all the similar questions and answers here... so in my viewDidLoad I have (tableView is actually a UICollectionView):

```
UINib * placeCell = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Shops" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:placeCell
   forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UICollectionView *)tableView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [_entries count];
    //return 5;

}

- (void)tableView:(UICollectionView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.item == [_entries count]-1 && page > 1) {
        NSLog(@"load more");
        //add footer view loading
        if (c_page == page) {
        //   _tableView.tableFooterView = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            c_page++;
            [self loadPlace:c_page];
        }
    }
}


    - (UICollectionViewCell *)tableView:(UICollectionView *)tableView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        PlaceCell *cell = (PlaceCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            UINib * placeCell = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Shops" bundle:nil];
            //cell = [cellLoader instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
            NSArray *topLevelItems = [placeCell instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];


        Place *p = [_entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.placeName.text = p.PName;
        NSLog (@"p:%@", p.PName")
        cell.placeImg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:p.PImage]]];
        return cell;
    }
```

I went into the xib of the UICollectionViewCell (PlaceCell) and made sure that "Cell" was the reuseidentifier. And I made sure that the datasource and delegate were connected to file's owner in the collectionView.

I also noticed that when I use a custom layout instead of the flow layout (like this one: https://github.com/ShadoFlameX/PhotoCollectionView/blob/master/CollectionViewTutorial/BHPhotoAlbumLayout.m ) it doesn't give me that error... but my collectionview still isn't populated.

So I'm wondering if there's some sort of log I can run or something I can do to figure out what's going wrong. Because I've tried all the solutions I've seen and it hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is: "Switched from UITableView to UICollectionView and no valid cell is being returned." It is really a two part answer. The crux of which is every instance of UITableView...

```
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-50)];
```

...you want to turn into "CollectionView"

```
_collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-50)];
```

Everything that's a "row":

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

...you'll want to turn into an "item."

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Ultimately I had to delete the following section entirely:

```
UINib * placeCell = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Shops" bundle:nil];
        //cell = [cellLoader instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        NSArray *topLevelItems = [placeCell instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];
```

My best guess is that the Nib was being loaded twice and that Xcode was complaining that the data wasn't being loaded by the original. So getting rid of that second entry got my cells loaded and populated with data. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a cell in a xib file you should register the xib, not the class. Also, when you register either the class or xib (or make the cell in the storyboard), you don't need an if (cell==nil) clause because your cell will never be nil when you dequeue it with dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:. You should delete that clause.

Comment: Updated the code above. Got rid of the "if" clause. Registered the xib instead of the class. It's still not even returning anything in the cells. (See my NSLog for P.Pname). Although it does in the old version with the table view. One thing I noticed Place *p = [_entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; I think that should be "indexPath.item". There were a lot of those since it used to be a tableview. So I switched them all to "indexPath.item".  Still no results though...

Comment: Is [_entries count] returning a non-zero value in numberOfItemsInSection?

Comment: It's really hard to say. Even in the tableview version I can't get the NSLog below to show up... but the table view cells load just fine in that version. Is there some log or something I can run on it to check?
    if (indexPath.row == [_entries count]-1 && page > 1) {
        NSLog(@"load more");

Comment: @mysticcola What do you mean it's hard to say? Just log [_entries count] in numberOfItemsInSection, and see what it says.

Comment: I mean exactly, precisely that. If I run NSLog(@"Count: %d", [_entries count]); Then I get nothing. Absolutely positively nothing. Not even "Count".

Comment: In the table view version I get "Count: 0".

Comment: @mysticcola Ok, so your data source methods aren't being called at all. Did you change the class of the controller in the storyboard (or xib) to your custom class?

Comment: Well it will only let me use PlaceCell. If you mean the class I registered it as (placeCell), then no I can't do that. It automatically capitalizes the "P" when I try to type it.

Comment: @mysticcola No, the view controller, not the cell is what I asked about. Is its class set in the storyboard or xib to whatever class the code you show in your question is.

Comment: Yes it is. As I said it's set to PlaceCell.

Comment: @mysticcola Sorry, I was confused by your poor choice of a name. You really should name your controllers with something that has controller in the name, it makes things much clearer. So, I have no idea what's wrong now. If the controller where you have the above code is the one that appears on screen, and you've set the data source and delegate, it should work. Without seeing your project,, I don't think there's anything else I can add.

Comment: Don't worry about it. You at least gave me some ideas. I just about have it solved. As the title of the question states... I was switching from a table view to a collection view... so in the end I had to change a LOT of things. I'll be writing my own answer when I'm done wrapping things up. Thanks.